# Unwanted effect with CSS animation hover happening a second time on each child

Tags: css, reactjs, css-animations

When applying a CSS transform based on a hover for my element which contains a title a summary and some other elements, all the children elements would move a second time when I hover over them inside the element.

Basically, the parent and its children(title, highlight...) will be animated a first time when I hover over it. **(this is the intended behaviour).**

But, if I hover over the title, it will apply the animation to the title individually, a second time. So, the title would be transformed a first time, let's say going up by 10px, and when I hover over it, it will go up again by 10 other pixels. The outer div (parent) will move only once. **(Unwanted)**

It is like I have applied their own animations to the parent and each one of the children.

*I tried to apply transform: none; to all the children elements, but, it does not help in my case.*

**CSS:**

```
.badge {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  transform: translateY(0);
  transition-duration: 1s;
  transition-property: transform;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-delay: 1s;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.badge:last-child {
  flex-basis: 100%;
}

.badge :hover {
  transform: translateY(-8px);
}

.badge__badge {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  margin-right: 40px; 
  width: 99%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: rgb(27, 139, 45);
  border-radius: 8px;
  color: aliceblue;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 2px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);

}

.badge__prime {
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: auto;

}

.badge__content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;

}

.badge__icon {
  width: 40px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 10px;

}

.badge__highlight {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: 30px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

**JSX (React):**

```
      <div className="badge">
        <div className="badge__badge"
          style={{ backgroundColor: this.props.backgroundColor }}>
          <div className="badge__content">
            {this.props.prime ? <h4 className="badge__prime">PRIME</h4>
              : <h4 className="badge__prime">Free</h4>}
            <h2 className="badge__title">{this.props.titleBadge}</h2>
            <div className="badge__highlight">
              {this.props.highlightBadge.split('\n').map((i, key) => {
                return <div key={key}>{i}</div>;
              })}
            </div>
          </div>
          <img className="badge__icon"alt="" src={this.props.iconBadge} />
        </div>
      </div>
```

***Expected results:*** the parent div and all its children will animate once on hover and will come back to their state once the mouse is outside of the div.

***Actual results:*** The parent div and all its children animate once on hover, and the children will animate again if the mouse is over one of them.

[Link to a jsfiddle that shows my issue](https://jsfiddle.net/fastblast/2enu5r1p/10/)

Comment: a few things you are missing a . to specify badge is a class. Also when transforming from a hover event you need to state the start and the end. Under .badge{} change transform: translateZ(0) to translateY(0) so it matches your :hover state. Or vice versa

Comment: @GifCo Thank you for your answer. The missing point is on my css file, I just missed it while copying. I am going to update my post with a JSFiddle that recreates my issue.

Comment: You have a typo in the css `.badge :hover` There shouldn't be a space there `.badge:hover`

Comment: @disinfor That solved the issue. Thank you a lot!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn what is expected of you when you ask a question.

Comment: @disinfor, answers go down there. You've short-circuited the Stack Exchange process.

Comment: @isherwood I generally don't post answers if it was a typo in the code - otherwise I'd have way more SO rep :)

Comment: I can do nothing from my side, right?